# migration in laravel for PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, stored-procedures

I am trying to create procedure migration in laravel but I am getting syntex error every time I tried so but didn't make it work

Below is the code

```
$this->addSql("CREATE PROCEDURE Type_Store_Sync(IN name_it VARCHAR(255), IN guid VARCHAR(32), IN type VARCHAR(10), IN orgid INT(11), IN scheme VARCHAR(6)) LANGUAGE SQL
        BEGIN
            CALL mysql.lambda_async( 
  'arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2::function:triggersync',
                CONCAT('{ \"name\" : ', REPLACE(name_it,'\\','\\\\'), ', \"guid\" : ', guid,', \"type\" : ', type,', \"orgid\" : ', orgid,', \"scheme\" :', scheme,'\"}')                
            );
        END");
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'), ', "guid"
> : ', guid,', "type" : ', type,', "orgid" : ', orgid,', "scheme" '

Comment: Always save SQL text into the variable and veify/test it. Try `.. REPLACE(name_it,'\\\\','\\\\\\\\'), ..`.

Comment: @Akina it's working. thanks